# Scope in a Sub Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I am trying to call a scope from multiple sub queries but I don't know how to do alternatively to a classic list (in (contract scope)). I need to use these subqueries to aggregate data.

Do you have an idea to refer to the initial scope only once or make it a bit more dynamic instead of changing the list of contracts 3 times?

Here is my query a bit simplified:

```
Select column1,column2,column3
From 
table u (nolock) on u.id in (scope of contracts here)
left join
  (Select b.user_id, sum(column)
   from table b
   Where b.user_id in (scope of contracts here)
   Group by b.user_id) Table1 on u.id = Table1.user_id 
left join 
  (Select b.user_id, sum(column)
   from table b
   Where b.user_id in (scope of contracts here)
   Group by b.user_id) Table2 on u.id = Table2.user_id "
```

Comment: I formatted your question to have indenting.  This makes a big difference when you talk to other programmers because they need to be able to read your code to understand it.

Comment: Is the issue here that "scope of contract" might change from one join to the other?

Comment: Please coulld you give a concrete example, including both example data and desired results?  That will help people understand what you mean and be more able to help you, as described here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers. No, the scope of contract should remain the same, I just put a left join in case a table doesnt have the contract. I was thinking of a text variable but it doesnt work in the in. Otherwise creating a table with the values but I don't have writing access unfortunately...

Comment: so why do you have two joins --- what is the difference between table1 and table2?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And use the current, not deprecated, syntax if you must.

Comment: "a classic list (in (contract scope))" & "scope of contracts here" are extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There may by additional details that are not included, but here are my comments on your code as written:

- Both Table1 and Table2 are the same -- there is no reason as shown why you need two joins.  I expect you made the example to simple and there are differences between the two but without knowing what that is I can't tell you how to make it better.
- As written your code limits the contacts in the u table with an in statement.
  `From table u (nolock) on u.id in (scope of contracts here)` This means that all contacts in u will be filtered.  You don't need the filter in the sub-queries because that will already occur with join.  You can only left join to items that in u.  So the query will be exactly the same functionally if you write it like this:

  ```
  Select column1,column2,column3
  From table u (nolock) on u.id in (scope of contracts here)
  left join
    (Select b.user_id, sum(column)
     from table b
     Group by b.user_id) Table1 on u.id = Table1.user_id 
  left join 
    (Select b.user_id, sum(column)
     from table b
     Group by b.user_id) Table2 on u.id = Table2.user_id
  ```

> Note: any modern optimizer will not be impacted by this change -- so
> don't worry about these sub-queries doing "extra work" without the
> where statement.

Comment: It's quite complicated actually. 
The table "b" quoted here is huge, without a filter in the subquery it will returns millions of results, the join will come after to filter but it would take too long...
So I need to filter already in the subqueries which take different data to aggregate. I am not sure this is clear sorry

Comment: @Tristan_Velo -- No.  This is my point.  What you describe is not how SQL Server works.  The sub-query won't return millions of results -- the join will filter.  Try it.

Comment: Hey Hogan, this works! I am really surprised an a bit shameful actually.
Many thanks for your help!